# Beautifulsoup : Difference between .find() and .select()

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

When you use ***[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)*** to scrape a certain part of a website, you can use

- `soup.find()` and `soup.findAll()` or
- `soup.select()`.

Is there a difference between the `.find()` and the `.select()` methods?
(e.g. In performance or flexibility, etc.) Or are they the same?

Comment: `select()` accepts CSS selectors, `find()` does not

Comment: See https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find and https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

Comment: But i don't really understand the difference between them. Because for me, they can do the same things. And i would like to know the difference.
(actually, i've a small preference for the .select())

Comment: select finds multiple instances and returns a list, find finds the first, so they don't do the same thing. `select_one` would be the equivalent to find.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - but you can do select("div nth-of-type(1)")  etc... + most of the time, I just start from an "id" in the "html" page, and go down to my wanted element ... . but when i've I use find/findAll - then i've some troubles .... e.g. if you want to do something like   soup.select("div[id=foo] > div > div > div[class=fee] > span > span > a")

Comment: I almost always use css selectors when chaining tags or using `tag.classname`, if looking for a single element without a class  I use find. It comes down to the use case and personal preferance. As far as flexibility goes I think you know the answer, `soup.select("div[id=foo] > div > div > div[class=fee] > span > span > a")` would look pretty ugly using chained find/find_all

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - true,  but yeah :) sometimes, when i scrape, i've the question - where those people drunk?? who made that website ...
e.g. you start from the div with id "container" and then you've literally a tree of divs and classes with the same name. or even better, they aren't using a "id"  at all :s

Comment: The only issue with the css selectors in bs4 is the very limited support,  `nth-of-type` is the only pseudo class implemented and chaining attributes like `a[href][src]` is also not supported as are many other parts of css selectors. But `a[href*=..]` and `a[href^=]` etc.. are very handy.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you have very good points in the comments. Why don't you summarize them into an answer?

Comment: @alecxe, I will throw something together in a bit, maybe a few timing comparisons would complete the answer

Comment: Please don't use `findAll()` anymore, as it doesn't follow Python's naming conventions.  There's a `find_all()` method.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

To summarise the comments:

- *select* finds multiple instances and returns a list, *find* finds the first, so they don't do the same thing. *select_one* would be the equivalent to *find*.
- I almost always use css selectors when chaining tags or using *tag.classname*, if looking for a single element without a class I use *find*. Essentially it comes down to the use case and personal preference.
- As far as flexibility goes I think you know the answer, `soup.select("div[id=foo] > div > div > div[class=fee] > span > span > a")` would look pretty ugly using multiple chained *find/find_all*  calls.
- The only issue with the css selectors in bs4 is the very limited support, *nth-of-type* is the only pseudo class implemented and chaining attributes like a[href][src] is also not supported as are many other parts of css selectors. But things like *a[href*=..]* , *a[href^=]*, *a[href$=]* etc.. are I think much nicer than `find("a", href=re.compile(....))` but again that is personal preference.

For performance we can run some tests, I modified the code from an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37541879/2141635) running on 800+ html files taken from [here](https://github.com/johnlaudun/tedtalks/tree/master/html_files/talks), is is not exhaustive but should give a clue to the readability of some of the options and the performance:

The modified functions are:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from glob import iglob


def parse_find(soup):
    author = soup.find("h4", class_="h12 talk-link__speaker").text
    title = soup.find("h4", class_="h9 m5").text
    date = soup.find("span", class_="meta__val").text.strip()
    soup.find("footer",class_="footer").find_previous("data", {
        "class": "talk-transcript__para__time"}).text.split(":")
    soup.find_all("span",class_="talk-transcript__fragment")



def parse_select(soup):
    author = soup.select_one("h4.h12.talk-link__speaker").text
    title = soup.select_one("h4.h9.m5").text
    date = soup.select_one("span.meta__val").text.strip()
    soup.select_one("footer.footer").find_previous("data", {
        "class": "talk-transcript__para__time"}).text
    soup.select("span.talk-transcript__fragment")


def  test(patt, func):
    for html in iglob(patt):
        with open(html) as f:
            func(BeautifulSoup(f, "lxml")
```

Now for the timings:

```
In [7]: from testing import test, parse_find, parse_select

In [8]: timeit test("./talks/*.html",parse_find)
1 loops, best of 3: 51.9 s per loop

In [9]: timeit test("./talks/*.html",parse_select)
1 loops, best of 3: 32.7 s per loop
```

Like I said not exhaustive but I think we can safely say the css selectors are definitely more efficient.

Comment: I used select to retrieve instances of a dt class name. Instead of giving me all the result, it always ends up giving 10 instances. Is there a default value to be altered?

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan, are you sure the html is not broken or not added dynamically somehow?

Comment: I had to issue a scroll down command to load the html completely. Though the page was loaded, the html did not. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: The `find…()` methods don't need the `class_=` or a dictionary with just a `"class"` key because if there's just as string as second argument that's the class value.

Comment: css selectors are awesome even with limited scope of `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: The limited nature of CSS selectors is pretty outdated information as selectors are now implemented by soupsieve and are much more powerful. While it is true there is still some limitation (no pseudo-elements and some non-applicable pseudo-classes as they don't apply in non-browser environments), there is a lot that is now supported: https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham , was wondering if the performance is still valid now? with version 4.9.3?

Comment: today select is so powerful ,