# Bs4 select_one vs find

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I was wondering what is the difference between performing `bs.find('div')` and `bs.select_one('div')`. Same goes for `find_all` and `select`.

Is there any difference performance wise, or if any is better to use over the other in specific cases.

Answer (score 11):

`select()` and `select_one()` give you a different way navigating through an HTML tree using the [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) which has rich and convenient syntax. Though, the CSS selector syntax support in `BeautifulSoup` is *limited* but covers most common cases.

Performance-wise, it really depends on an HTML tree to parse and on which element, how deep is it and what selector is used to locate it. Plus, what `find()` + `find_all()` alternative there is to compare the `select()` with, is also important. In a simple case like `bs.find('div')` vs `bs.select_one('div')`, I'd say that, generally, `find()` should perform faster simply because [there is a lot going on to support CSS selector syntax under-the-hood](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/element.py#L1331).

Answer (score 4):

select_one is  normally much faster than find:

```
In [13]: req = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/")

In [14]: soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")

In [15]:  soup.select_one("#DESCRIPTION")
Out[15]: <h2 id="DESCRIPTION">DESCRIPTION</h2>

In [16]:  soup.find("h2", id="DESCRIPTION")
Out[16]: <h2 id="DESCRIPTION">DESCRIPTION</h2>

In [17]: timeit  soup.find("h2", id="DESCRIPTION")
100 loops, best of 3: 5.27 ms per loop

In [18]: timeit  soup.select_one("#DESCRIPTION")
1000 loops, best of 3: 649 µs per loop

In [19]: timeit  soup.select_one("div")
10000 loops, best of 3: 61 µs per loop
In [20]: timeit  soup.find("div")
1000 loops, best of 3: 446 µs per loop
```

*find* basically is just the same as using  *find_all* setting the limit to 1, then checking if the list returned is empty or not, indexing,  if it is not empty or returning None if it is.

```
def find(self, name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None,
         **kwargs):
    """Return only the first child of this Tag matching the given
    criteria."""
    r = None
    l = self.find_all(name, attrs, recursive, text, 1, **kwargs)
    if l:
        r = l[0]
    return r
```

*select_one* does something similar using *select*:

```
def select_one(self, selector):
        """Perform a CSS selection operation on the current element."""
        value = self.select(selector, limit=1)
        if value:
            return value[0]
        return None
```

The cost is much lower with the select without all the keyword args to process.

[Beautifulsoup : Is there a difference between .find() and .select() - python 3.xx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38028384/beautifulsoup-is-there-a-difference-between-find-and-select-python-3-x/38033910#38033910) covers a bit more on the differences.

Comment: Since this is one of the top google results: Cannot confirm those results for `select` vs `find_all` on a live site I tested with `lxml` parser searching for all <li> elements with a specific class. Used timeit with 1000 runs and find_all was slightly faster than select (1s).