# Finding a keyword in a text

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have lines like these :

```
[b'\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td><a href=info.php?id=Cre35.g759247.t1.1+ target="_blank">Cre35.g759247.t1.1 </a></td>']
[b'\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td><a href=info.php?id=Cre17.g739850.t1.2 target="_blank">Cre17.g739850.t1.2</a></td>']
[b'\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td><a href=info.php?id=Cre17.g737200.t1.2 target="_blank">Cre17.g737200.t1.2</a></td>']
```

I'm after the word that starts with "Cre" and ends with ".t"number"."number.

How exactly can I extract it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't need regex and can rely on the [attribute = value css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) with contains (*) operator

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''[b'\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td><a href=info.php?id=Cre35.g759247.t1.1+ target="_blank">Cre35.g759247.t1.1 </a></td>']
[b'\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td><a href=info.php?id=Cre17.g739850.t1.2 target="_blank">Cre17.g739850.t1.2</a></td>']
[b'\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td><a href=info.php?id=Cre17.g737200.t1.2 target="_blank">Cre17.g737200.t1.2</a></td>']'''

soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
items = [i.text for i in soup.select("[href*='php?id=Cre']")]
print(items)
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I retrieve the fasta sequence and the length of sequence from this page in a similar fashion: 

https://phytozome.jgi.doe.gov/phytomine/portal.do?class=Protein&externalids=Cre06.g250300.t1.2

Comment: thx, the website is currently acting up, the problem is I can see the information regarding fasta and the length of the sequence on the website, but when I run beutiful soup  and ctrl+f to find that information, I can't find it, and hence, no coding attempt

Comment: one moment whilst I look for cached version

Comment: you can find many of these entries here: http://chlamyfp.org/readcsvfile_js.php, thx to your code, now I can retrieve all of them, but what I want to ultimately do, is get their sequence and length. Also, I wonder if I can "select" certain lines that come after my "[href*='php?id=Cre']" selection,? and what is the anatomy of this selection, I want to be able to select other stuff i na similar way

Comment: what do you mean by sequence and length?

Comment: it's working now! I mean the "length" which is 287 and the "fasta" which gives a string of letters, that's their length https://phytozome.jgi.doe.gov/phytomine/portal.do?class=Protein&externalids=Cre12.g511750.t1.2

Comment: I did shft+ctrl+p and disabled java, anyway the line I'm after is: <script> imSummaryFields["length"] = "287";</script> how can I pull the length from that line? Also, from line <a href="/phytomine/sequenceExporter.do;jsessionid=5CB1AFBB3169F9A23D9818EFD9300D0E?object=118068893" target="_new"><img class="fasta" how can I pull the number "118068893"?

Comment: thanks, you're really good! but what does select_one() does exactly

Comment: it applies the css selector within the quotes to the html and returns the first match. Also faster. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033612/bs4-select-one-vs-find ,  https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/# , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: ok great, I will definitely try to learn that stuff, but for now what about retrieving the number for fasta or fasta sequence directly?

Comment: ? what do you mean. Code extracts both of those for you.  For sequence I think you have to mimic the button push (xhr request) as shown in pastebin.

Comment: oh, but sometimes I get     length = soup.select_one('.value').text.strip()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text', I also realized the website has an API,  but I couldn't find the python script they mentioned here: https://phytozome.jgi.doe.gov/phytomine/api.do?subtab=python

Comment: Test if the variable returned is None before attempting to access .text else return N/A or other value

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do the trick: `Cre.*?\.t\d\.\d` It first looks for `Cre` literally, followed by any characters (but as few as possible), and then ends with a literal `.` and `t`, a digit, a `.`, and another digit.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/GaWDUL/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''[b'\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td><a href=info.php?id=Cre35.g759247.t1.1+ target="_blank">Cre35.g759247.t1.1 </a></td>']
[b'\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td><a href=info.php?id=Cre17.g739850.t1.2 target="_blank">Cre17.g739850.t1.2</a></td>']
[b'\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td><a href=info.php?id=Cre17.g737200.t1.2 target="_blank">Cre17.g737200.t1.2</a></td>']'''

# BeautifulSoup -> parsing source of the HTML.

soup = BeautifulSoup(html) 

print(soup)

# View HTML code.
print(soup.prettify())

# Get infomation
site_names = soup.find_all('a')

for site_name in site_names:
    print(site_name.get_text())
```

Comment: Thanks, Jee Mok. I can't stack_overflow well.