# BeautifulSoup returns empty brackets

Tags: python, google-chrome, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get how many results have a search in Google with bs4 library in python, but while doing it, it returns empty brackets.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url_page = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=covid&oq=covid&aqs=chrome.0.0i433l2j0i131i433j0i433j0i131i433l2j0j0i131i433j0i433j0i131i433.691j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8'

page = requests.get(url_page).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

elTexto = soup.find_all(attrs ={'class': 'LHJvCe'})
print(elTexto)
```

I have an extension in google that check if the html class is correct and it gives me what I'm looking for so I guess that is not the problem.... Maybe is something related with the format of the 'text' I'm trying to get...
Thanks!

Comment: Google is randomizing class names to prevent just exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use [gsearch](https://pypi.org/project/gsearch/) package to accomplish your task, rather than scraping the web page manually.

Answer (score 0):

Google is **not** randomizing classes as [baduker mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67299803/beautifulsoup-returns-empty-brackets#comment118956374_67299803). They could change some `class` names over time but they're not randomizing them.

One of the reasons why you get an empty result is because you haven't specified HTTP `user-agent` aka [`headers`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers), thus Google might block your request and `headers` might help to avoid it. You can check what is your `user-agent` [here](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent). Headers will look like this:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

requests.get('YOUR URL', headers=headers)
```

Also, you don't need to use `find_all()`/`findAll()` or `select()` since you're trying to get only one occurrence, not all of them. Use instead:

- `find('ELEMENT NAME', class_='CLASS NAME')`
- `select_one('.CSS_SELECTORs')`

[`select()`/`select_one()` usually faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39036044/15164646).

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Number-of-Total-Search-Results-python-bs4#main.py) (*note: the number of results will always differ. [It just works this way](https://tinybullyagency.com/why-googles-search-results-vary-from-person-to-person/).*):

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "fus ro dah defenition",
  "gl": "us",
  "hl": "en"
}

response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

number_of_results = soup.select_one('#result-stats nobr').previous_sibling
print(number_of_results)

# About 104,000 results
```

---

Alternatively, you achieve the same thing using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi, except you don't need to figure out why certain things don't work and instead iterate over structured JSON string and get the data you want.

Code:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "fus ro dah defenition",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

result = results["search_information"]['total_results']
print(result)

# 104000
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.