# BeautifulSoup: Classify parent and children element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a question about BeautifulSoup in Python 3.I spent a couple of hours to try but I have not solved it yet.

This is my soup:

```
print(soup.prettify())
# REMEMBER THIS SOUP IS DYNAMIC
# <html>
#  <body>
#   <div class="title" itemtype="http://schema.org/FoodEstablishment">
#    <div class="address" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
#      <div class="address-inset">
#        <p itemprop="name">33 San Francisco</p>
#      </div>
#    </div>
#    <div class="image">
#      <img src=""/>
#      <span class="subtitle">image subtitle</p>
#    </div>
#    <a itemprop="name">The Dormouse's story</a>
#   </div>
#  </body>
# </html>
```

I have to extract two text by `itemprop="name"`: `The Dormouse's story` and `33 San Francisco` But I want need way to define what class is the parent.

Expected output:

```
{
   "FoodEstablishment": "The Dormouse's story",
   "PostalAddress": "33 San Francisco"
}
```

Remember the soup is always dynamic and have many chilren elements in it.

Comment: clarify what is your expected output ?

Comment: Updated, bro. Please

Comment: Once you have targeted the tag, you can just use attribut `parent` to get the parent tag

Comment: @Maaz `parent` is useful for a simple soup. I want to say about a complex soup which have many parents

Comment: `soup.findAll("div", itemtype=True):`

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη and then?

Comment: and what about `parents` to get all the parents as a list?

Comment: @Maaz Can you do the code. I'll pick you confirmed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use `soup.find` when you can use `soup.select`, get help from all the CSS wiz kids **and** test your criteria in a browser first?

There's a [performance benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38028384/beautifulsoup-is-there-a-difference-between-find-and-select-python-3-x) on SO and `select` is faster, or at least not significantly slower, so that's not it.  Habit, I guess.

(works just as well without the `<p>` tag qualifier, i.e. just `"[itemprop=name]"`)

```
found = soup.select("p[itemprop=name]")

results = dict()

for node in found:

    itemtype = node.parent.attrs.get("itemtype", "?")
    itemtype = itemtype.split("/")[-1]
    results[itemtype] = node.text

print(results)
```

### output:

It is what you asked for, but if many nodes existed with FoodEstablishment, last would win, because you are using a dictionary.  A defaultdict with a list might work better, for you to judge.

```
{'PostalAddress': '33 San Francisco', 'FoodEstablishment': "The Dormouse's story"}
```

#### step 1, before Python:  rock that CSS!

[image]

#### and if you need to check higher up ancestors for `itemtype`:

it would help if you had html with that happening:

```
    <div class="address" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
      <div>
        <p itemprop="name">33 San Francisco</p>  
      </div>

    </div>
```

```
found = soup.select("[itemprop=name]")

results = dict()

for node in found:

    itemtype = None
    parent = node.parent
    while itemtype is None and parent is not None:
      itemtype = parent.attrs.get("itemtype")
      if itemtype is None:
        parent = parent.parent


    itemtype = itemtype or "?"
    itemtype = itemtype.split("/")[-1]
    results[itemtype] = node.text

print(results)
```

same output.

#### using a defautdict

everything stays the same except for declaring the results and putting data into it.

```
from collections import defaultdict
...
results = defaultdict(list)
...

results[itemtype].append(node.text)
```

output (after I added a sibling to 33 San Francisco):

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'PostalAddress': ['33 San Francisco', '34 LA'], 'FoodEstablishment': ["The Dormouse's story"]})
```

Comment: Thanks for your approach. This approach may work. But do you think about the approach which get list of  `itemtype` first. Then find in `children` elements the `itemprop`? I'll pick you the best if you support this approach, as same as your approach.

Comment: ??? I don't understand what you are saying, sorry.  Why don't you try the different answers and see what works best?  Don't forget to add a case where the `itemtype` is **not** found on the direct parent of `itemprop` element, because right now your test html does not have that.  For me - but I am not talking about other answers - I would **not** search on `itemtype` and then find children with `itemprop`, too complicated.

Comment: @KitKit in fact I would add `<div class="address" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
      <div>
        <p itemprop="name">33 San Francisco</p>  
        <p itemprop="name">34 LA</p>  
      </div>
    </div>` and see what happens.  only 34 LA is in the result, which is why I recommend you use a defaultdict.

Comment: I tried with your code and fix something and now It works properly. I think this is the best solution for my issue. Thank you very much, bro

Answer (score 2):

I get the itemtype and contents of each tag, then create a dictionary using update.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<html>
 <body>
  <div class="title" itemtype="http://schema.org/FoodEstablishment">
     <div class="address" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
     <p itemprop="name">33 San Francisco</p>
   </div>
   <p itemprop="name">The Dormouse's story</p>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
"""
d = {}
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.findAll("div"):
    # get the last string in itemtype separated by /
    itemType = item.get("itemtype").split('/')[-1]
    # remove newline(\n) from contents
    itemProp = list(filter(lambda a: a != '\n', item.contents))
    # create a dictionary of key: value
    d.update({itemType: itemProp[-1].text}) 

print(d)

Result: {'FoodEstablishment': "The Dormouse's story", 'PostalAddress': '33 San Francisco'}
```

Comment: Your approach is ok. I tried this approach before I post this issue into stackoverflow. But I get issue when soup have a complex structure (<p itemprop="name"> have many parent wrappers)

Comment: many thanks - your approach is great - i am a learner of python and i learned alot!! Keep up your great work

Answer (score 1):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """<html>
 <body>
  <div class="title" itemtype="http://schema.org/FoodEstablishment">
   <div class="address" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
     <p itemprop="name">33 San Francisco</p>
   </div>
   <p itemprop="name">The Dormouse's story</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

a = [item.get("itemtype") for item in soup.findAll("div", {'itemtype': True})]
b = soup.find("div", {'itemtype': True}).get_text(
    strip=True, separator="|").split("|")

print(a)
print(b)
```

output:

```
['http://schema.org/FoodEstablishment', 'http://schema.org/PostalAddress']
['33 San Francisco', "The Dormouse's story"]
```

Update:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

names = [item.text for item in soup.findAll("p", itemprop="name")]
print(names)
```

Output:

```
['33 San Francisco', "The Dormouse's story"]
```

Comment: Remember this soup is dynamic and have many elements in it. I updated the HTML soup

Comment: @KitKit well, i don't understand your requirement, based on what you want to match ?

Comment: Can you have the code which get a list of all elements which have attribute `itemprop="name"`  and then check the closest parent `itemtype`?

Comment: @KitKit ok let's walk through the process as i try to understand you. check the update. now we got the list. now what you want next?

Comment: How to know the wrapper element in each output? Ex: '33 San Francisco' => `PostalAddress ` and "The Dormouse's story" => `FoodEstablishment `