# BeautifulSoup4: find_all() | When attempting to find elements that have been assigned multiple classes, how do you specify only some of them?

Tags: python, html, class, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Currently I'm attempting to scrape Metacritic for new video game releases, gathering the titles of games and their respective scores. The problem I am facing involves each score on the website being assigned multiple classes in the HTML. Each score has been assigned 4 different classes, and I only wish to specify 3.

Example: `<div class="metascore_w large game positive">80</div>`

Elements containing **metascore_w**, **large**, and **game** are what I wish to collect. In particular, **game** is essential because without this class, it returns unhelpful miscellaneous scores such as movies, tv shows, and music.

The class **positive** cannot be used because it only specifies positive reviews, when I also want to collect mixed and negative reviews as well (which have their class name as such.) Though I would prefer to not have to specify positive, mixed, and negative for simplicity's sake, if it must be done I will gladly do so.

---

The specific issue I am facing is a head-scratcher. If I specify the starting class, it outputs just fine:

```
scores = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'metascore_w'}) print(scores)

[<div class="metascore_w medium game positive">90</div>, <div class="metascore_w medium movie positive">80</div] (etc)
```

If I specify all 4 classes, it outputs just fine as well:

```
scores = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'metascore_w large game positive'}) print(scores)

<div class="metascore_w large game positive">80</div>, <div class="metascore_w large game positive">84</div> (etc)
```

But when I specify 3 classes, I receive no output:

```
scores = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'metascore_w large game'}) print(scores)

[]
```

---

If anyone has any idea how I could solve this problem, I would greatly appreciate it! Thank you for reading!

Comment: Use CSS selectors, e.g., `soup.select('div.metascore_w.large.game')`. The classes won't need to be in a particular order, i.e, ``soup.select('div.large.game.metascore_w')`` should work too.

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: https://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/new-releases/all/date

Comment: @JustinEzequiel This definitely seems like a step in the right direction, but another problem I didn't foresee has come up!

The inclusion of user made scores, with the class user, are being delivered alongside the intended official scores. Is there any way to exclude them?

<div class="metascore_w user large game mixed">6.1</div>
<div class="metascore_w large game mixed">71</div>

Comment: Here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38033910/5386938) discussing `soup.select(...)`.

Comment: Try `soup.select(':not(.user).metascore_w.large.game')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get titles and metascores from the site, you can use this example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = (
    "https://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/new-releases/all/date"
)

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

for h3 in soup.select(".product_groups_wrapper h3"):
    title = h3.text
    metascore = h3.find_next(class_="metascore_w").text
    print("{:<50} {:<4}".format(title, metascore))
```

Prints:

```
Subnautica: Below Zero                             80  
Assassin's Creed Valhalla: Wrath of the Druids     71  
Resident Evil Village                              84  
Hood: Outlaws & Legends                            64  
Wreckfest                                          78  
Shin Megami Tensei III: Nocturne HD Remaster       78  
Mass Effect Legendary Edition                      89  
Resident Evil Village                              81  
Skate City                                         64  
The Colonists                                      73  
Subnautica: Below Zero                             84  
Assassin's Creed Valhalla: Wrath of the Druids     73  
Resident Evil Village                              85  
Hood: Outlaws & Legends                            61  
Before I Forget                                    88  
Mass Effect Legendary Edition                      90  
Dull Grey                                          55  
Protocol                                           49  
NieR Replicant ver.1.22474487139...                83  
Smelter                                            82  
Shin Megami Tensei III: Nocturne HD Remaster       82  
Subnautica: Below Zero                             78  
Famicom Detective Club: The Missing Heir           74  
Famicom Detective Club: The Girl Who Stands Behind 74  
Skate City                                         67  
Shin Megami Tensei III: Nocturne HD Remaster       77  
Siege Survival: Gloria Victis                      65  
Days Gone                                          78  
Subnautica: Below Zero                             82  
Mass Effect Legendary Edition                      85  
World of Demons                                    80  
Fantasian                                          79  
CLAP HANZ GOLF                                     80  
The Oregon Trail                                   76  
Crash Bandicoot: On the Run!                       59
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andrej and Justin! Both of these will really help out!